# getting css objects to change on hover and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm having a problem with my css code, I want a list item to stay the same after it is clicked on. This is my CSS.

```
.exploreheadings{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .7s;
    transition: font-size .7s;
}

.exploreheadings:hover{
    font-size: 50px;
}
.exploreheadings:active{
    font-size: 50px;
}

.exploreheadings:visited{
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

and this is my html

```
<ul>
    <li class="exploreheadings">people</li>
    <li class="exploreheadings">hashtags</li>
    <li class="exploreheadings">businesses</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way I can get this to stay the same after I hover over it and click on it, I tried the visited selector, but to no avail. I am semi-new in the programming world, so it might be a stupid mistake, but can anyone help? I am also comfortable in using jQuery, so if thats what it has to be, I'm fine with it.

Comment: Are you using javascript? there's nothing to click...

Comment: I'm not using javascript, but is there a way to use jQuery to solve this problem, I thought the ":visited" selector would work.

Comment: `:visited` applies to anchor elements, of which you have none. (Also, you can't use jQuery without using JavaScript: jQuery *is* JavaScript.)

Comment: I mean there is no click action happening here, so nothing would be changing on "click"

Comment: Is there a selector which can affect the list item the same as    :visited?

Comment: Ohhhhh, ok, I've got it now, thanks guys.

Comment: *"Is there a selector which can affect the list item the same as :visited?"* I don't think so. But you can easily add a click-handler with JS/jQuery that adds a class upon click. Note though that if you want the user to be able to click you should use anchor elements anyway (so that users who don't have a mouse or pointing device can still access that functionality via the keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

Without much context, try the following code. It'll persist your visual states:

```
<ul>
<li class="exploreheadings" onclick="setactive(this);">people</li>
<li class="exploreheadings" onclick="setactive(this);">hashtags</li>
<li class="exploreheadings" onclick="setactive(this);">businesses</li>
</ul>
<script>
function setactive(d){
  var os=d.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i=0;i<os.length;i++){
    var o=os[i];
    o.style.fontSize='30px';
  }
  d.style.fontSize='50px';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery is an option, following sets the font-size and removes the transition:

```js
$(".exploreheadings").click(function () {
    $(this).css({
        "transition": "none",
        "font-size": "50px"
    });
});
```

```css
.exploreheadings {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .7s;
    transition: font-size .7s;
}

.exploreheadings:hover {
    font-size: 50px;
}
.exploreheadings:active {
    font-size: 50px;
}
.exploreheadings:visited {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="exploreheadings">people</li>
    <li class="exploreheadings">hashtags</li>
    <li class="exploreheadings">businesses</li>
</ul>
```

**Update:** to change the other li elements back to 30px font size when another li is clicked, following approach using `toggleClass()` and an additional class `active` that is a copy of the class `exploreheadings` with the adjusted font-size of 50px and without the transition:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("li").click(function () {
          $("li.active").toggleClass("exploreheadings active");
          $(this).toggleClass("exploreheadings active");
      });

  });
```

```css
.exploreheadings {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .7s;
    transition: font-size .7s;
}
.active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.exploreheadings:hover {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="exploreheadings">people</li>
    <li class="exploreheadings">hashtags</li>
    <li class="exploreheadings">businesses</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two of the pseudo-classes you're using (:active, and :visited) only work on `a` elements. 
Add `a` elements to your HTML as follows:

```
<ul>
   <li class="exploreheadings"><a href="#">people</a></li>
   <li class="exploreheadings"><a href="#">hashtags</a></li>
   <li class="exploreheadings"><a href="#">businesses</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then change your CSS to style link states on the `a` elements rather than on the `li` elements:

```
.exploreheadings a:hover {
    font-size: 50px;
}
.exploreheadings a:active {
    font-size: 50px;
}
.exploreheadings a:visited {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

**Edited to clarify that while `:hover` works with other elements, `:active` and `:visited` work only with `a` elements.

Comment: `:hover` works just fine on other elements, just not the others

Comment: Good point. Edited response to reflect this. The original poster's code doesn't work specifically because `:visited` works only for `a` elements.